# Texy syntax of anchor and span

Tags: syntax

I would like to generate this html markup with Texy editor?

```
<a href="/url" class="button">
    <span>Redirect</span>
</a>
```

How to write in Texy syntax this anchor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search any solution is possible only this way:

```
/--html
<a href="/url" class="button"><span>Redirect</span></a>
\--
```